# Android ksoap2 request cannot make as required

Tags: android, soap, soapui, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I have a soap xml which should be generated by **ksoap2** in Android. Please help me to generate this. I am new in Android Soap.

SoapUI generated xml is :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <app:fetchAllDoctorSpecialityWise xmlns:app="http://app.shl.com/">
         <userid>?</userid>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <password>?</password>
         <specialityID>?</specialityID>
      </app:fetchAllDoctorSpecialityWise>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am using below code to generate this :

```
 boolean result = false;
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://***.***.com/***/fetchAllDoctorSpecialityWiseRequest";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "app:fetchAllDoctorSpecialityWise";
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://***.***.com/";
        String url = "http://apps.***************.com:8080/app/***";
        int timeOut = 180;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("userid", username);
        request.addProperty("password", password);
        request.addProperty("specialityID", specialityid);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true; // Set this variable to true for
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(true);
        // compatibility with what seems to be the
        // default encoding for .Net-Services.
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        System.out.println(envelope);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Log.e("SOAP RETURN", "Request XML:\n" + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            Log.e("SOAP RETURN", "\n\n\nResponse XML:\n" + androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("myApp", envelope.toString());
            System.out.println("response" + envelope);

        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Log.e("Error : ", "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error : ", "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am stuck with this help me out. BTW I think "app" tag is not generating properly, which is the main issue.

Comment: Try to change your `METHOD_NAME` from `app:fetchAllDoctorSpecialityWise` to `fetchAllDoctorSpecialityWise`.

Comment: I have got the solution by using below changes. Thnx to all of you. 
SoapObject soapReq = new SoapObject("", "app:fetchAllDoctorSpecialityWise ");
        soapReq.addAttribute("xmlns:app", NAMESPACE);